# NHibernate: How to map a column on a referenced table to a primitive in my object?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

If I have the following existing table schema

```
+-------------------+        +-------------------+
|  Address          |        |  Country          |
+-------------------+        +-------------------+
|  Line1            |   +--->|  CountryId        |
|  Line2            |   |    |  Name             |
|  City             |   |    +-------------------+
|  State            |   |
|  Zip              |   |
|  CountryId        |---+
+-------------------+
```

...and my class is as follows

```
public class Address
{
    public virtual string Line1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Line2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
}
```

...how do I configure my mappings so that the `Country (string)` property contains the `[Name]` column from the `[Country]` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by mapping a view. But the object oriented approach would be to create a Country object and map the many-to-one relationship between Address and Country:

```
public class Address
{
    public virtual string Line1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Line2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
    public virtual string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

You would then access the name through Address.Country.Name. In FluentNHibernate you would use [References](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#References_.2F_many-to-one) to map the relationship in your Address mapping: 
`References(x=> x.Country, CountryId);`

Comment: Thanks, but I understand this clearly. I would still like to know how to achieve the above result.

Comment: Your above result or mine? The only way to achieve yours is by mapping a view as I stated.

Comment: I read this question early on and came up with the exact same answer as Jamie. I didn't post in case I was wrong about this, but in my experience with NHibernate, I have not seen any other way to create the mapping you're looking for without using a view. It's like Domain object normalization! Maybe you can map a private _country property and then create a public Country property that returns a string by doing _country.Name? Similar idea for setting.

Comment: Jon, I will reply with the Fluent NHibernate ClassMaps for this if that's what you;re looking for. Let me know.